# Selenide waitUntil(condition, timeout).isDisplayed() throws an error instead of returning a boolean

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-testing, selenide

I'm having a problem with controlling the test flow using Selenide waitUntil and conditional method isDisplayed(). I need my condition to check if the element is present&visible and if it is to return false; if it isn't then we proceed to checking if the next given element is enabled or not and based on that we either return false or proceed with the method.

I have this condition

```
if (Actions.waitUntilAppears(AWAITING_PAYMENT_DIV, 5_000) &&
            !Actions.waitUntilEnabled(PAY_WITH_CARD_BTN, 60_000)) {
        return false;
    }
```

the actions methods are

```
public static boolean waitUntilAppears(By locator, long timeForWait) {
    return $(locator).waitUntil(Condition.appear, timeForWait).isDisplayed();
}

public static boolean waitUntilEnabled(By locator, long timeForWait) {
    return $(locator).waitUntil(Condition.enabled, timeForWait).isEnabled();
}
```

However, I'm getting a selenide "assertions" error on first condition, e.g. in visibility check. It throws

```
Element not found {By.xpath: //div[text()='element text']}
Expected: visible
```

When the next condition worked perfectly fine on it's own, as in it returned a boolean which I used to control the while cycle in another method. I also can't catch the exception since it's technically "caught" within selenide "assertion", exception being Caused by: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: You get that error because your `waitUntil` expired. That means the element you are looking for do not exists in DOM. `isDisplayed` represents that the element is present in DOM, but is visible or not.

Comment: @KunLun I guess Selenide's javadoc of isDisplayed() is ambiguous then and I should just used exists() instead?

Comment: I would use like this: `boolean exists = false; try{ foo.waitUntil(...); exists = true; }catch(Exception ignored){}`

Comment: I ended up scratching the waitUntil method from my waitUntilAppears() action altogether, since it is probably not intended to be used as a true-false switch and is instead supposed to be an actual assertion. I am still not sure how to wait for an element to exist in my dom since I can only use Selenide and can't catch an exception it's waitUntil() throws since it's thrown and caught by assertion within the method itself.